# MySQL Delete on date and time comparision

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `appointments` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`app_date` date NOT NULL,
`mobile` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
`time` time NOT NULL,
`duration` int(3) NOT NULL,
`services` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(32) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `appointments` (`id`, `app_date`, `mobile`, `time`, `duration`, 
`services`, `status`) VALUES
(11, '2017-09-28', '991694', '11:00:00', 1, 'PP', 'Booked'),
(12, '2017-09-28', '991694', '12:00:00', 1, 'FT', 'Booked'),
(13, '2017-09-29', '991694', '10:00:00', 1, 'HC;FT', 'Booked'),
(14, '2017-09-11', '991694', '11:00:00', 1, 'T;W;HS;PP', 'Booked');

 DELETE from appointments where 'mobile' = '991694' and 'app_date' = 
 '2017-09-28' and 'time' = '11:00:00'
```

is not deleting any row? returning 0 rows affected. Please suggest what is going wrong here.

Also i tried with
**DELETE from appointments where 'mobile' = '991694' and 'app_date' = date '2017-09-28' and 'time' = time '11:00:00'**

Comment: please read proper stackoverflow guideline before asking question here

Comment: @Rahul what exactly is wrong with this post, other than the formatting? It shows a clear example, with code to create the table, with the error and the problem and implies what the expected results should be. This is far better than 90% of the "PLEASE WRITE MY CODE FOR ME" posts we get. The fact that I was able to copy and paste this post into SQL and run it with the same results makes it light years better than most questions.

Comment: Hot tip 1: ALWAYS store dates and times as a single entity. Hot tip 2: Never store comma/colon/semicolon delimited data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quote before the column name. You ARE NOT checking the values on the rows, you are **COMPARING STRINGS**. Please notice that, in mysql

```
' != `
```

This should work:

`DELETE from appointments where mobile = 991694 and app_date = '2017-09-28' and time = '11:00:00'`